# Get function reference of class (not object)

Tags: javascript, object

I have a code where a function is used to modify the existing functions and return a new function reference. I want that function to be applied to specific methods of a class.
My current code is

```
function modifyMethod(func) {
  return function() {
    console.log('working');
    return func.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

function modifyClassMethods(ClassName, methodArray) {
  // The code goes here

  return ClassName;
}

class Temp {
  hi() {
    console.log("hi method");
  }
}

Temp = modifyClassMethods(Temp, ["hi"]);
const temp = new Temp();
// This should print
//
// working
// hi method
temp.hi();
```

When I try to call the method `modifyMethod` with `Temp.hi`, `func` is undefined. If I create an object and then modify the method, then the new method will be applied only to the method of that particular object and not to all the objects of that particular class.

Note that this is just an example. I want to apply this modification to the methods of multiple classes. So, I can't generalize the method names also. Any code snippet for the `modifyClassMethods` will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods defined with method syntax in the body of a `class` construct that aren't marked `static` are *prototype methods* and so they're on `Temp.prototype`, not `Temp` itself. So that's where you'd update them:

```
Temp.prototype.hi = modifyMethod(Temp.prototype.hi);
```

Only *static* methods end up on `Temp` itself.

You may see other functions created within the `class` body using the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)'s syntax:

```
class Temp {
    hi = () => {
        //
    };
}
```

Those are *instance methods*. They're created by the constructor, and re-created for each instance, roughly as though they'd been written like this:¹

```
class Temp {
    constructor() {
        this.hi = () => {
            //
        };
    }
}
```

You can't wrap those until/unless an instance is created, as they're instance-specific.

So to wrap up, consider:

```
class Temp {
    static staticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
    prototypeMethod() {
        // ...
    }
    instanceMethod = () => {
        // ...
    };
    constructor() {
        this.anotherInstanceMethod = () => {
            // ...
        };
        this.yetAnotherInstanceMethod = function {
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```

That class shows the three types of methods:

- **Static Methods**, such as `staticMethod`, which you'll find on `Temp` (e.g., `Temp.staticMethod`);
- **Prototype Methods**, such as `prototypeMethod`, which you'll find on `Temp.prototype` (e.g., `Temp.prototype.prototypeMethod`); and
- **Instance Methods**, such as `instanceMethod`, `anotherInstanceMethod`, and `yetAnotherInstanceMethod`, which you'll find on the instances themselves, if/when any instances are created

---

¹ Technically, they're created as though with `Object.defineProperty` like this:

```
class Temp {
    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "hi", {
            value: () => {
                //
            },
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}
```

...not via simple assignment. I used simple assignment in the example to keep it...simple. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. But, in case if the method is created using Arrow function i.e. ```hi = () => {}```, Temp.prototype.hi is not working.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal - Those aren't methods per se, they're arrow functions assigned to the instance by the constructor. They don't exist until/unless an instance is created, and you can't wrap them until/unless an instance is created.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal - Happy to help! I've updated the answer to call out the three types of methods.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal - I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that I cover all of this in Chapters 4 and 18 of my book; details in my profile. ;-)